# ValueError: unknown url type: '[<a href=

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm creating something using BeautifulSoup that will scrape until it returns 5 paragraphs, but right now it only works up until a certain point. I'm not entirely sure where the problem is. Why does it say "unknown url type"?

The main parts of my code are

```
def parse_page(page_url):
    count = 0

    article = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'mw-content-text'})

    if article is None:
        return
    else:
        paragraphs = article.find_all('p')
        extracted_this_page = []

        links_this_page = article.find_all('a', href = re.compile('(/wiki/)+'))

        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            text = paragraph.text
            if user in text:
                record = {
                    'text':text,
                }
                if record != None:
                    print(record)
                    count = count + 1
                    extracted_this_page.append(record)
        return extracted_this_page, count, links_this_page
```

```
def call_parse_page(links):
    print('Start')
    tracker = 0
    my_set_count = 0
    my_links_this_page = 'my_links_this_page'
    for link in links:
        url = link['href']
        print(url)
        if url.startswith('http') == False:
            url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + url

        my_extracted_this_page, my_count, my_links_this_page = parse_page(url)
        extracted.append(my_extracted_this_page)
        tracker = tracker + 1
        my_set_count = my_set_count + my_count
        print(my_set_count)

        if my_set_count >= 5:
            print('Success!')
            return extracted
        elif my_set_count < 5 and len(links) != tracker:
            continue
        else:
            parse_page(my_links_this_page)
```

While it is working:

```
Parsing...
{'text': "At the end of 2012, Flamengo elected Eduardo Bandeira de Mello as club president for three years. The goal of his term was to improve the club's finances after an independent audit assessed Flamengo's debt at R$750\xa0million.[37] After a typical series of managerial changes, Jayme de Almeida was appointed as interim manager during which he fought off relegation and won the 2013 Copa do Brasil final against Atlético Paranaense. It was Flamengo's third Copa title, after 1990 and 2006.\n"}
4
/wiki/Club_Atl%C3%A9tico_River_Plate
```

Error:

```
Parsing...
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wikipedia_pt3.py", line 76, in <module>
    print(call_parse_page(my_links))
  File "wikipedia_pt3.py", line 74, in call_parse_page
    parse_page(my_links_this_page)
  File "wikipedia_pt3.py", line 20, in parse_page
    request = urllib.request.Request(page_url, headers={'User-Agent':user_agent})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '[<a href="/wiki/Template:Months" title="Template:Months"><abbr style=";;background:none transparent;border:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none; padding:0;" title="View this template">v</abbr></a>, <a href=
```

Comment: Like the error message says, you passed `'[<a href="/wiki/Template:Months" title="Template:Months"><abbr style=";;background:none transparent;border:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none; padding:0;" title="View this template">v</abbr></a>, <a href='` as a URL.

Comment: How can I separate the chunk into links that I can work with?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you print the URL every step as it gets transformed through your function. Then you'll know when it becomes "not a URL".

Comment: Okay, thanks so much!

Comment: @heliona203 https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Thanks